# Wordpress Multisite new sites in directory

Tags: multisite, content, directory

Is it possible to make a wordpress multisite on domain.com and then every site that I make goes to domain.com/directory/newsite?

and then I have another question: is it also possible to that every new site has no content, so the whole site is empty?

Comment: Did you ever work this out?

Comment: @Djave, regarding the directory name in the subsite path would this be helpful? https://paulund.co.uk/wordpress-multisite-with-nested-folder-paths

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to make a wordpress multisite on domain.com and then every site that I make goes to domain.com/directory/newsite?

no, this is not possible without some major code hacking as far as I can tell.  I run a few multisites, and I have some local installations to play around and didn't manage to find a way to do this within the exsiting process-flow, although I would be happy to be proven wrong.

However, there is a way to achieve a similar result with a single-site installation in the root directory and a [multisite sub-directory installation](https://wordpress.org/support/article/create-a-network/#step-3-installing-a-network) in a sub-folder.  This would give,

- domain.com as the single site installation in the root folder.
- domain.com/folder/ as the main site of the sub-directory multisite installation which would need to be redirected back to the domain.com.
- domain.com/folder/site1
- domani.com/folder/site2...

the downside of this approach is that it would create 2 separate dashboards and 2 separate DBs, although it would be easier to maintain/upgrade on the long-term than  a hacked WP multisite installation.

> and then I have another question: is it also possible to that every new site has no content, so the whole site is empty?

by this question I am assuming you mean no pages/posts which are created by default on creation.

When a new site is created the [wp_insert_site](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_site/) action hook is fired, so you can use that to clear your content with the [switch_to_blog](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/switch_to_blog/) function call.  I would use [wp_delete_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_delete_post/) as there is only 2 posts to delete.

```
add_action('wp_insert_site', 'clear_site_content',10,2);
function clear_site_content($new_site){
  switch_to_blog($new_site->id);
  wp_delete_post(1, true);
  wp_delete_post(2, true);
  restore_current_blog();
}
```

if you use [wp_cli](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/) there is the function [wp_site_empty](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/site/empty/) which you could use to the do the same thing, but that is over-kill in my opinion.